# Linq to SQL: Group By and Sum from 3 table Join

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a query as below with some issues on converting that to LINQ.

Query is:

```
SELECT P.ProjectID, MIN(ProjectName) As PrjName, SUM(Hours * Rate) As Price
FROM Projects P 
        INNER JOIN Tasks T ON P.ID = T.ProjectID
        INNER JOIN Timesheets Time ON T.TaskID = Time.TaskID
GROUP BY P.ProjectID
```

My best attempt on Linq is (not quite working yet):
Problems are at the ??

```
 var q = from p in db.Projects
                join t in db.Tasks on p.ProjectID equals t.ProjectID
                join time in db.Timesheets on t.TaskID equals time.TaskID
                group p by p.ProjectID into g
                select new { ID = g.Key, Name = ??, Price = g .Sum(x => x??)};
```

or

```
    var q = (from p in db.Projects
            join t in db.Tasks on p.ProjectID equals t.ProjectID
            join time in db.Timesheets on t.TaskID equals time.TaskID into g
              select new {p.ProjectName, g.Sum(x => x.Hours * x.Rate)
              ); --get invalid anonymous type at Hours * Rate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from p in Projects
      join t in Tasks on p.Id equals t.ProjectID
      join ts in Timesheets on t.TaskID equals ts.TaskId
      group t by new { proj= p, timesheet = ts} into g
      select  new
        {
           g.Key.proj.Id,
           g.Key.proj.ProjectName,
           Price = g.Key.timesheet.Rate * g.Key.timesheet.Hours
        }
```

Comment: My g.Key.xx does not give me options like proj and timesheet.  I found it in other Linq queries as well.  Can it be a version difference?  I'm using VS2012.  The only intellisense items I see for g.Key.x is CompareTo, Equals, GetHashCode, GetType, GetTypeCode and ToString.

Comment: have you added the `{ proj= p, timesheet = ts}` part?  that's what gives you the extra options

Comment: My apologies.  Thanks for that.